# php mysql fetch data from mulitiple table in json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Please help, I need to fetch data from two tables, and encode it in json my table are

1. `Customers_table`

> id | inv_id | customer_name | address | total_value

2. `Items_table`

> id | inv_id | description | details | qty | unit_price

my PHP code is as followws

```
<?php
require "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT customers_table.id,
                customers_table.inv_id,
                customers_table.customer_name,
                customers_table.address,
                customers_table.total_value,
                items_table.inv_id,
                items_table.description,
                items_table.details,
                items_table.inv_id,
                items_table.qty,
                items_table.ubit_price,
                items_table.amount,

                FROM customers_table INNER JOIN items_table ON
                customers_table.inv_id = items_table.inv_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    array_push($response);
    }

echo json_encode(array(
    "server_response" => $response
));
mysqli_close($db)
?>
```

but JSONLint response is

```
{
    "server_response": []
}
```

please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: array_push needs 2 parameters 1) array 2) result

Comment: for array_push you need an empty array then the main array, making it parameters

Comment: why not do something like `$response[] = $row`?

Comment: you need to connect your db to query the sql

Comment: @Akin, How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_push()` accepts two parameters like this `array_push($array, $element_to_be_pushed)`. [array_push reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

You can rewrite same code by using `$array[]`, this will push new elements to the next available index.

**Try this code:**

```
<?php
require "config.php";
$sql ="SELECT customers_table.id,
                customers_table.inv_id,
                customers_table.customer_name,
                customers_table.address,
                customers_table.total_value,
                items_table.inv_id,
                items_table.description,
                items_table.details,
                items_table.inv_id,
                items_table.qty,
                items_table.ubit_price,
                items_table.amount
                FROM customers_table INNER JOIN items_table ON
                customers_table.inv_id = items_table.inv_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $response[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=> $response));
mysqli_close($db)
?>
```

**Updated answer :**

extra comma "`items_table.amount,`" removed.

Comment: I still get the same response, could it not be the select statement that is wrong? please help me check

Comment: var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result)) run this and tell me what are you getting.

Comment: you've extra comma at "items_table.amount,". check updated code

Comment: I got this NULL {
 "server_response": []
}

Comment: it is still same result

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: run this query on mysql directly and check whether query is returning result or not

Comment: yes, I am using phpmyadmin, but couldn't run it on mysql, it is throwing error, I have sent you fb friend request, please accept so we can chat directly

Comment: @LaideLawal great to hear that mate :)